# Excel VBA 438 Error Raised on PC but not on Mac

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA code which adds to a custom Edge class object to a dictionary of dictionaries. I am using [this Dictionary class](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Dictionary).

This works as expected on Mac, but when I try to run my spreadsheet command on a PC I get a `438: Object doesn't support this property or method` error.

The line of code raising the error is `edges_dict(user)(Provider) = created_edge` where `edges_dict(user)` is a dictionary, `Provider` a String, and `creaded_edge` an Edge.

If I instead use `edges_dict(user).Add Provider, created_edge` everything works well, but I want the overwrite ability the first call provides. Additionally, `edges_dict(key) = value` works. The issue seems to arise from my nesting.

Here is the code where I create the dictionary of dictionaries:

```
Public edges_dict As New Dictionary 'Stores in degrees
Public s_array() As String

Public single_node As Dictionary 'Dictionary keyed by source node holding in degree edges for a certain node

Sub Generate_Matrix()


    'Code to populate s_array() here

    'Populate dictionary with key as node, value as array of inbound edges to be filled
    Set single_node = New Dictionary

        edges_dict.Add s_array(I), single_node 

    Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: *The issue seems to arise from my nesting*. Yes, it does. Don't nest implicit default member calls, keep your sanity. Pull the inner dictionary from the outer one into its own local variable, work with that dictionary reference, and avoid implicit default member calls.

Comment: Could you please provide an example? When I try Set v = edges_dict(user) / v(Provider) = created_edge, I get the same error

Comment: I did a quick test and it seems like setting any dictionary value to an object of the Edge class fails on PC but not on Mac. I’ve tested this on multiple machines.

Comment: Keyword is "setting" indeed. See below answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
edges_dict(user)(Provider) = created_edge
```

There's *a lot* going on, crammed into that little instruction. If either key lookup fails, how do you know which key failed? You don't, and you can't know.

Split it up, there's no use trying to compact as much functionality as possible into a single instruction.

```
Dim providers As Dictionary
Set providers = edges_dict.Item(user)
```

As a bonus, you get *IntelliSense* and early binding!

> creaded_edge an Edge.

Assuming an `Edge` is an object, the bug isn't with the Win32 code blowing up with error 438 - the bug is with the Mac code "working" when it should absolutely be complaining about the missing default member on the `Edge` class.

The error is indirectly telling you that you need a `Set` keyword to assign that object reference:

```
Set providers(provider) = created_edge
```

Without the `Set` keyword, you are let-coercing the `created_edge` object, which means the dictionary item associated to that key is NOT an object on the "working" Mac code, but whatever data type the class' default member is... assuming it *has* a default member (and it doesn't... so it's unclear how/why the Mac code isn't blowing up) - here's your "nested" instruction, with the implicit code in square brackets:

```
[Let] edges_dict[.Item](user)[.Item](Provider) = created_edge[.DefaultMember]
```

The reason why `.Add` works in both cases, is because no let-coercion is happening in that case: the object reference itself is being added as a value.

Error 438 is being thrown because let-coercing an object that *doesn't* have a default member (as seems to be the case), is *supposed* to fail.

Adding `Set` in front of the assignment would fix it... but does not behave the same as `.Add`: `.Add` will throw a *duplicate key* error if you try to re-add an existing key, while assigning the keyed value like you did will silently *replace* the value associated to an existing key.

Comment: You would know which key failed if the `Dictionary` was properly implemented. On Mac the class rely on a `Collection` via `Remove/Add` and is not object sensitive while on PC, the class rely on the Windows `Scripting.Dictionary` via `Let/Set`.